# Accordion JS plugin, CSS3 webkit

Tags: javascript, classes

**Accordion plugin**

As I don't use jQuery (because I just have fun with Chrome and iOS/Android) and I prefer to write my own functions, I decided to write a simple Accordion function some time ago:

- Short code
- High performance
- Latest JS CSS3 HTML5 technologies

I don't want to add many classes and ids, and many eventhandlers. (My iPad 1 is very sensitive with too many eventhandlers and they are also a pain to delete if needed)

> This function adds no ids, no extra classes and uses only one eventhandler.

#### Single Accordion:

Code for single Accordions (you can apply this function to more elements but you can't put accordions inside accordions.):

```
function acsf(e) {
    var Accordion = e.target.parentNode;
    if (Accordion.parentNode == this && Accordion.firstChild == e.target) {
        if (this.CurrentAccordion == Accordion) {
            this.CurrentAccordion.style.height = '';
            delete this.CurrentAccordion
        } else {
            !this.CurrentAccordion || (this.CurrentAccordion.style.height = '');
            this.CurrentAccordion = Accordion;
            this.CurrentAccordion.style.height =
                (Accordion.firstChild.offsetHeight +
                this.CurrentAccordion.childNodes[1].offsetHeight) + 'px'
        }
    }
}
```

Structure (no new lines or spaces between `<>`):

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div>
        <div>Title</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Title</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordion')[0].addEventListener('click',acsf,false);
```

The above code works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/zhD5L/

**But** I want to create a plugin that adds this function to every element with the accordion class and include it as a script:

```
(function() {
 function acsf() {
  //the code above
 }
 function init(){
  var acs = D.getElementsByClassName('accordion'),
  acsl = acs.length;
  while(acsl--){
      acs[acsl].addEventListener('click',acsf,false);
  }
  window.removeEventListener('load',init,false);
 }
 window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
})()
```

Is this correct, or are the better ways to do that?

Should this remove the possibility of creating problems with other variable or function names?

---

I also want to be able to put accordions inside accordions, so I wrote this next script, but there is a delay and I totally don't know how to remove that.

I also don't want to use settimeout.  That was just the only way I knew to get it work vs `webkitAnimationEnd` which just needs a little more code.  But I need to get the next height before the animation or timeout ends.

```
(function (D) {
    function acsf(e) {
        var a = e.target.parentNode,
            h;
        if (a.parentNode == this && a.firstChild == e.target) {
            h = a.firstChild.offsetHeight;
            !this.c || (this.c.style.height = h + 'px');
            this.c != a ?
                (this.c = a, this.c.style.height = (h + this.c.childNodes[1].offsetHeight) + 'px') :
                (this.c.style.height = h + 'px', delete this.c);
            setTimeout(acscf.bind(this), 350);
        }
    }

    function acscf(x) {
        x = this;
        if (x.parentNode && x.parentNode.parentNode &&
            x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode &&
            x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList) {
            var y = x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (y.classList.contains('accordion')) {
                console.log(x.offsetHeight);
                y.c.style.height = (48 + (x.offsetHeight)) + 'px';
                setTimeout(acscf.bind(y), 350);
            }
        }
    }

    function acsinit() {
        var acs = D.getElementsByClassName('accordion'),
            acsl = acs.length;
        while (acsl--) {
            acs[acsl].addEventListener('click', acsf, false);
        }
        window.removeEventListener('load', acsinit, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', acsinit, false);
})(document)
```

Example to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8dzh/

^ the latest accordion title contains other 2 accordions

---

And now to make things difficult I'm trying to find a way to interact with the closed function outside of it. So basically toggle elements with another function created inside another script.

---

#### To resume the questions:

1. Create a plugin to include that does not create problems with other scripts. (I'm totally new to JS classes)
2. Remove the delay
3. I want to be able to toggle the elements outside with a function outside of the plugin.

**EDIT**

I just found out that I could use `try` `catch` vs the long check on the `parentNode`s.

```
if(x.parentNode && 
   x.parentNode.parentNode &&
   x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode &&
   x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList..
```

to

```
try{
 y=x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains('accordion')
}catch(e){
 y=false
}
```

But what about performance?

Comment: What happened to the indentation? You really use 1 space and no whitespace? It reads like minified code.

Comment: i personally use only 1 space and no white spaces .. but in this case i also use it so there is no need to scroll.

Comment: this is how i wrote it first http://jsfiddle.net/zhD5L/1/ i use notepad.

Comment: But this is a code review site, the indentation is the very first thing I'd notice, plus the name of your variables, it doesn't help either. Many people will pass on your question after a first glance at the code.

Comment: so you think i should delete the question?

Comment: I think you could just name your variables right, and use this service to indent your code http://jsbeautifier.org/. Unless of course, you want people to comment on those things. No need to close the question.

Comment: better now ? what you think?

Comment: Yes, I submitted a little edit for review, but it looks much better. I suppose the problematic variable names are up for review.

Comment: And what you think about the questions?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a lot of style problems, so many style problems that it would take a long time to figure out what it does. Well written code does not pose this problem. I can really only point out what you are doing wrong style wise and after the code is cleaned up, perhaps we ( or you yourself ) can figure out your questions.

- There is not a single comment
- `Accordion` starts with an uppercase, that should be reserved for constructors
- This is a shortcut for `if`, do not use this unless you are code golfing:

  ```
  !this.CurrentAccordion || (this.CurrentAccordion.style.height = '');
  ```
- Over the top abbreviations like `acsf` should be avoided
- One character variables should be avoided ( except perhaps for the common `i`,`s` and `e` )
- This makes my eyes bleed, what does it do?? :

  ```
  this.c != a ?
      (this.c = a, this.c.style.height = (h + this.c.childNodes[1].offsetHeight) + 'px') :
      (this.c.style.height = h + 'px', delete this.c);
  ```

  using comma's to chain statements is plain wrong in a ternary
- I have no idea why you would need to do this:

  ```
  if (x.parentNode && x.parentNode.parentNode &&
      x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode &&
      x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList) {
  ```

  this is extremely brittle, at the very least I would do a recursive lookup on `parentNode` until I find something on the element that identifies it as the right level. Or build a function that gives the n-th level parent, but then it's brittle again. ( Meaning that a change in HTML layout will break your function ).

Comment: After reading what code golfing means, well yes i always do that.I want a short performant code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21353032/2450730 ,http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45335/33435. i use shorthand or/& bitwise operators over standard one as they perform faster on most browsers. btw i see no examples in you answer. your just criticizing my code. actually there is no answer in your response that i could apply to my code.reguarding the last answers that checks the parentnode: brittle but performant. i already answered that with another solution with is shorter but loses in performance

Comment: http://jsperf.com/parseint-multihttp://jsperf.com/bw-math http://jsperf.com/multiple-functions http://jsperf.com/store-array-vs-obj/2 http://jsperf.com/if-short here are some performance tests.

Comment: and explain why using commas to chain is wrong pls.

Comment: Given that you know how to write code golf code, I did not think it was necessary to tell you how to write your code with `if` statements instead. Comma chained statements in a ternary should be handled by an `if` statement

Comment: Furthermore,  criticizing code actually is an answer on CodeReview. What I am telling you in my review is that your code is too hard to grok, and hence too hard to fix. Write your code first in a readable manner, and then perhaps you will find the trouble. I am sorry if I hurt your feelings, but know that this code is a maintenance nightmare (you cannot fix it yourself!).

Comment: "Comma chained statements in a ternary should be handled by an if statement" why?

Comment: Readability & maintainability, there is no technical reason.